# python-find out the number with equal 1's in it's binary representation as that in the input number

Tags: python, count, binary

I'm new in python programming. just got stuck with this one problem. I have to take a natural number n as input and output will be a natural number m such that m>n and number of 1's in m's binary representation = number of 1's in n's binary representation.(sample input:23, output:27) here's what i wrote. I'm having trouble with the while loop.

```
n=int(input('input number:'))
x=''
for i in range(1,n+1):
    x=str(n%2)+x 
    n>>=1

List=[]

for i in x:
    List.append(i)
n_count=List.count('1') 
m=n+1
y=''
while m>n:
    for i in range(1,m+1):
        y=str(m%2)+y 
        m>>=1

    List2=[]
    for i in y:
        List2.append(i)
    m_count=List2.count('1')

    if m_count==n_count:
        print (m)
        break

    m=m+1
```

Comment: Rather than rolling your own, you can just use `bin()` to get the binary representation of an integer.

Comment: This would make a good code golf question. I've got it down to 7 lines and I'm convinced it could be much shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like homework, so I'll just give you a hint. You can use the `bin` function to get the binary representation of an integer, rather than doing all that bit twiddling. To get a number with the same number of ones, just add a zero anywhere but in the first place, and check out what the second argument to `int` does to get back a number.

Comment: There's a variation of this answer that gives the *smallest* number with the same bit count that's greater than the input.

Answer (score 2):

Since `bin()` returns a string representing the binary value and `count()` returns the number of times a substring appears in a string, you can loop until you find a number.  Since this looks like homework, here's a general idea:

```
while m > n: # this may as well say "while True:", so maybe think of a better condition.
    m += 1
    if bin(m).count('1') == bin(n).count('1'): # if you find a better condition you won't need an if statement.
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really a problem with understanding binary numbers in general. Remember that multiplying a number by 2 doesn't change the number of 1s. So you can just do `n*2`.

You can verify it by doing

```
n=int(input('input number:'))
m= n*2

print 'm is', m
print "n's 1s", bin(n).count('1')
print "m's 1s", bin(m).count('1')
print "m > n", m > n
```

Comment: Although it's not mentioned, I'm betting that the OP is supposed to return the *smallest* such number.

Comment: Oh well that makes things nontrivial. Though still fairly simple if you understand binary.

Answer (score 1):

`m = n<<1`

the `<<` operator is a left *binary shift*.  It moves everything in the binary representation to the left by one place and inserts a zero at the right end.  this will double the value of the number, but note affect the number of `1`s because you're just moving the bits around.

some examples

```
0001 << 1 == 0010
0010 << 2 == 1000
0101 << 1 == 1010
1000 >> 1 == 0100
```

This operation is faster than multiplication, and can be used to replace it when multiplying by a power of two.

```
>>> 5*2 == 5 << 1
True
>>> 10*4 == 10 << 2
True
>>> 3*8 == 3 << 3
True
```

Think of it this way.  If I asked you "what's 868554 * 6 ?" you'd have to do some thinking.  But if I said "what's 456103284 * 10 ?" you'd just add a 0 to the right end.  Computers can do a similar thing, but with *2 instead of *10